# compare string in 3 areas

Tags: php, comparison, compare

i want to compare a number in 3 areas

for example:

when $a is > 0 and < 80 echo RED

when $a is > 80 and < 100 echo YELLOW

when $a is > 100 echo RED

the problem with my code now is: when $a=80 i got no result

here is my code:

```
<?php

$a=80;

if(($a > 0) && ($a < 80))
{
echo('RED');
}
if(($a > 80) && ($a < 100))
{
echo('YELLOW');
}
if($a > 100)
{
echo('GREEN');
}

?>
```

you can see the test with $a=79 [here](http://codepad.org/XqKXqKTZ)

and with $a=80 [here](http://codepad.org/mKNv45ok)

how can i realize this? maybe in a smaller and nicer way :D

don't know if it's important.. but $a can be 80.1 and can be bigger than 100

Comment: What are you expecting when you use 80? Red or yellow?

Comment: the issue is you're not covering 80. You only have greater or lesser than 80. Not greater than or equal to / less than or equal to 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine which color you want `80` to be. in this example I'll make it `RED`

```
$a=80;

if(($a > 0) && ($a <= 80)){
    echo('RED');
}elseif(($a > 80) && ($a < 100)){
    echo('YELLOW');
}elseif($a > 100){
    echo('GREEN');
}
```

Do you notice the `=` in `$a <= 80`

Additionally, you will run into the same problem with `100` and `0` so you will need to deal with those as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<=` (less than or equal to) and `>=` (greater than or equal to) symbols to close this gap:

```
if(($a > 0) && ($a <= 80)) {
    echo('RED');
} if(($a > 80) && ($a <= 100)) {
    echo('YELLOW');
} if($a > 100) {
    echo('GREEN');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to do 2 conditions per statement, as you can just do this

```
<?php
    $a = 80;
    if ($a > 0) {
        if ($a <= 80) echo "RED";
        else if ($a <= 90) echo "YELLOW";
        else echo "GREEN";
    }
?>
```

**Update**: Rewrote my code to fit `from 0 to 80 RED from 80.000001 to 90 YELLOW`